Dual of the direct sum of Banach spaces
Let us consider two Banach spaces $\mathbb E_1$ and $\mathbb E_2$. Let us equip the direct sum $\mathbb E_1\oplus\mathbb E_2$ with the two norm, i.e.,
$$
      \left\Vert (\xi,\zeta) \right\Vert_2:=(\left\Vert\xi \right\Vert^2_{\mathbb E_1} +\left\Vert \zeta \right\Vert_{\mathbb E_2} ^2 )^{\frac{1}{2}}
$$
and let us denote this space as $\mathbb E_1\oplus_2\mathbb E_2$. I want to show that
$$
     (\mathbb E_1\oplus_2\mathbb E_2)^*\simeq \mathbb E_1^*\oplus_2\mathbb E_2^*.
$$
The bijection between the two spaces is given by setting
$$
      F:\mathbb E_1^*\oplus_2\mathbb E_2^*\to (\mathbb E_1\oplus_2\mathbb E_2)^*
$$
assigning to $(\varphi,\psi)\in E_1^*\oplus_2\mathbb E_2^*$ the element $F_{\varphi,\psi}$ defined as
$$
    F_{\varphi,\psi}\cdot(\xi,\zeta):=\varphi\cdot\xi+\psi\cdot\zeta\qquad\forall(\xi,\zeta)\in\mathbb E_1\oplus_2\mathbb E_2.
$$
It is also clear that
$$
    \left\Vert F_{\varphi,\psi} \right\Vert_{(\mathbb E_1\oplus_2\mathbb E_2)^*}
    \leq
    \left\Vert (\varphi,\psi) \right\Vert_{\mathbb E_1^*\oplus_2\mathbb E_2^*}.
$$
To prove that $ \left\Vert F_{\varphi,\psi} \right\Vert_{(\mathbb E_1\oplus_2\mathbb E_2)^*}
    \geq
    \left\Vert (\varphi,\psi) \right\Vert_{\mathbb E_1^*\oplus_2\mathbb E_2^*}$ I'm having difficulties. Indeed, knowing that
$$
    \left\Vert F_{\varphi,\psi} \right\Vert_{(\mathbb E_1\oplus_2\mathbb E_2)^*}:=\sup\left\{ \left|(\varphi,\psi)\cdot(\xi,\zeta)\right| \;:\;(\xi,\zeta)\in\mathbb D^1(\mathbb E_1\oplus_2\mathbb E_2)\right\},
$$
where $\mathbb D^1(\mathbb E_1\oplus_2\mathbb E_2)$ is the unit disk in $\mathbb E_1\oplus_2\mathbb E_2$ w.r.t. the 2-norm, we can rewrite
$$
\left|(\varphi,\psi)\cdot(\xi,\zeta)\right|= \left|\varphi\cdot\xi+\psi\cdot\zeta\right| . 
$$
Now, from the definition of $\left\Vert \varphi \right\Vert_{\mathbb E_1^*} $ and $\left\Vert \psi \right\Vert_{\mathbb E_2^*} $, for every $\varepsilon>0$ we can find $\xi_\varepsilon\in\mathbb D^1(\mathbb E_1)$ and $\zeta_\varepsilon\in\mathbb D^1(\mathbb E_2)$ such that
$$
\varphi\cdot\xi_\varepsilon\geq(1-\varepsilon) \left\Vert \varphi \right\Vert_{\mathbb E_1^*}
\qquad
\textrm{and}
\qquad
\psi\cdot\zeta_\varepsilon\geq(1-\varepsilon) \left\Vert \psi \right\Vert_{\mathbb E_2^*}  
$$
and hence
$$
\left|\varphi\cdot\xi+\psi\cdot\zeta\right|
\geq
(1-\varepsilon) (\left\Vert \varphi \right\Vert_{\mathbb E_1^*} + \left\Vert \psi \right\Vert_{\mathbb E_2^*})
\geq
(1-\varepsilon) (\left\Vert \varphi \right\Vert_{\mathbb E_1^*}^2 + \left\Vert \psi \right\Vert_{\mathbb E_2^*}^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}
=
(1-\varepsilon) \left\Vert (\varphi,\psi )\right\Vert_{\mathbb E_1^*\oplus_2\mathbb E_2^*}.
$$
What I'm missing is how I can use this to conclude
$(\xi_\varepsilon,\zeta_\varepsilon)\in\mathbb D^1(\mathbb E_1\oplus_2 \mathbb E_2)$.
Thank you in advance

If $\|\varphi\|_{\mathbb{E}^*_1}=\|\psi\|_{\mathbb{E}_2^*}=0$, this is trivial. So assume $\|\varphi\|_{\mathbb{E}^*_1}^2+\|\psi\|_{\mathbb{E}_2^*}^2>0$. By homogeneity, it suffices to consider the case that $\|\varphi\|_{\mathbb{E}^*_1}^2+\|\psi\|_{\mathbb{E}_2^*}^2=1$. As you said, for $0<\varepsilon<1$, pick $\xi_\varepsilon\in \mathbb{D}^1(\mathbb{E}_1)$ and $\zeta_\varepsilon\in \mathbb{D}^1(\mathbb{E}_2)$ such that $\text{Re }\varphi(\xi_\varepsilon)=|\varphi(\xi_\varepsilon)|>1-\varepsilon$ and $\text{Re }\psi(\zeta_\varepsilon)=|\psi(\zeta_\varepsilon)|>1-\varepsilon$.  Let $$g=\Bigl(\frac{\|\varphi\|_{\mathbb{E}_1^*} \xi_\varepsilon}{\sqrt{\|\varphi\|_{\mathbb{E}_1^*}^2+\|\psi\|_{\mathbb{E}_2^*}^2}},\frac{\|\psi\|_{\mathbb{E}_2^*}\zeta_\varepsilon}{\sqrt{\|\varphi\|_{\mathbb{E}_1^*}^2+\|\psi\|_{\mathbb{E}_2^*}^2}}\Bigr).$$
Then $$\|g\|_{\mathbb{E}_1\oplus_2\mathbb{E}_2} = \frac{\sqrt{\|\varphi\|_{\mathbb{E}_1^*}^2 \|\xi_\varepsilon\|_{\mathbb{E}_1}^2+\|\psi\|_{\mathbb{E}_2^*}^2 \|\zeta_\varepsilon\|_{\mathbb{E}_2}^2}}{\sqrt{\|\varphi\|_{\mathbb{E}_1^*}^2+\|\psi\|_{\mathbb{E}_2^*}^2}}\leqslant \frac{\sqrt{\|\varphi\|_{\mathbb{E}_1^*}^2 +\|\psi\|_{\mathbb{E}_2^*}^2}}{\sqrt{\|\varphi\|_{\mathbb{E}_1^*}^2+\|\psi\|_{\mathbb{E}_2^*}^2}}=1.$$
\begin{align*} |(\varphi,\psi)(g) |& \geqslant \frac{\|\varphi\|_{\mathbb{E}_1^*}^2(1-\varepsilon)+\|\psi\|_{\mathbb{E}_2^*}^2(1-\varepsilon)}{\sqrt{\|\varphi\|_{\mathbb{E}_1^*}^2+\|\psi\|_{\mathbb{E}_2^*}^2}}=(1-\varepsilon)\sqrt{\|\varphi\|_{\mathbb{E}_1^*}^2+\|\psi\|_{\mathbb{E}_2^*}^2}.\end{align*}
More generally, assume we're working over the scalar field $\mathbb{K}$ (either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$). let $I$ be a non-empty set, let $E$ be a Banach space, and let $(e_i)_{i\in I}\subset E$ be such that for each $e\in E$, there exists a unique $(a_i)_{i\in I}\subset \mathbb{K}$ such that $e=\sum_{i\in I}a_ie_i$, where the series is unconditionally convergent. We suppose also that for each $\sum_{i\in I}a_ie_i\in \text{span}\{e_i:i\in I\}$ and each $J\subset I$, $$\Bigl\|\sum_{i\in J}a_ie_i\Bigr\|_E\leqslant \Bigl\|\sum_{i\in I}a_i e_i\Bigr\|_E.$$  These conditions can be summarized by saying $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ is a $1$-suppression unconditional basis for $E$. In this case, the coordinate functionals $(e^*_i)_{i\in I}$ are also a $1$-suppression unconditional basis for their span in $E^*$. Without loss of generality, for simplicity, we assume $\|e_i\|=1$ for all $i\in I$.
For later, we note that if $(f_j)_{j\in J}$ is a $1$-suppression unconditional basis for a Banach space $F$, then for any $$f=\sum_{j\in J}a_jf_j\in F$$ and any collection $(w_j)_{j\in J}$ with $w_j\in [0,1]$ for all $j\in J$, it holds that $$\sum_{j\in J}w_ja_jf_j\in F$$ and $$\Bigl\|\sum_{j\in J}w_ja_jf_j\Bigr\|_F\leqslant \Bigl\|\sum_{j\in J}a_jf_j\Bigr\|_F.$$  We skip the details. The key observation is that $\sum_{j\in J}w_ja_jf_j$ is in the closed, convex hull of $$\Bigl\{\sum_{j\in H}a_jf_j:H\subset J\Bigr\},$$ and $1$-suppression unconditionality guarantees that each vector in this set has norm at most $\|\sum_{j\in J}a_jf_j\Bigr\|_F$.
We also note that if $(f_j)_{j\in J}$ is a $1$-suppression unconditional basis for a Banach space $F$, then for each subset $K$ of $J$, the map $\sum_{j\in J}a_jf_j\mapsto \sum_{j\in K}a_jf_j$ is a well-defined projection of norm at most $1$ (norm exactly $1$ except in the trivial case $K=\varnothing$). The restriction of the adjoint of this projection to $\text{span}\{f^*_j:j\in J\}$ is the projection $$\sum_{j\in J}b_jf^*_j\mapsto \sum_{j\in K}b_jf^*_j,$$ which is also norm at most $1$.
Let $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of Banach spaces and let $$E(X_i)=\Bigl\{(x_i)_{i\in I}:\sum_{i\in I}\|x_i\|e_i\in E\Bigr\}.$$ This is a Banach space with the norm $$\|(x_i)_{i\in I}\|_{E(X_i)}=\Bigl\|\sum_{i\in I}\|x_i\|e_i\Bigr\|_E.$$  We need $1$-suppression unconditionality to guarantee that this expression satisfies the triangle inequality.
Then for any $(x^*_i)_{i\in I}$ with $\{i\in I:x^*_i\neq 0\}$ finite, if $x^*=\sum_{i\in I}x^*_i$ is the functional in $E^*$ defined by $$(x_i)_{i\in I}\mapsto \sum_{i\in I}x^*_i(x_i),$$ it holds that $$\|x^*\|_{E(X_i)^*}=\Bigl\|\sum_{i\in I} \|x^*_i\|e^*_i\Bigr\|_{E^*}.$$  For the proof, we first note that if $x=(x_i)_{i\in I}$ satisfies $\|x\|_{E(X_i)}=1$, then \begin{align*} |x^*(x)| & \leqslant \sum_{i\in I}|x^*_i(x_i)| \leqslant \sum_{i\in I}\|x^*_i\|\|x_i\| = \sum_{i\in I}\|x^*_i\|\|x_i\|e^*_i(e_i)\\ & = \Bigl(\sum_{i\in I} \|x^*_i\|e^*_i\Bigr)\Bigl(\sum_{i\in I}\|x_i\|e_i\Bigr) \leqslant \Bigl\|\sum_{i\in I}\|x^*_i\|e^*_i\Bigr\|_{E^*}\|x\|_{E(X_i)} \\ & = \Bigl\|\sum_{i\in I}\|x^*_i\|e^*_i\Bigr\|_{E^*}. \end{align*}
On the other hand, fix $0<\theta<1$. For each $i\in I$, pick $x_i\in \{x\in X_i:\|x\|\leqslant 1\}$ such that $$\text{Re }x^*_i(x_i)=|x^*_i(x_i)|>\sqrt{\theta}\|x^*_i\|.$$  There exists $$e=\sum_{i \in I}a_ie_i\in \{f\in E:\|f\|\leqslant 1\}$$ such that $$\text{Re }\Bigl(\sum_{i\in I}\|x^*_i\|e^*_i\Bigr)(x)=\Bigl|\Bigl(\sum_{i\in I}\|x^*_i\|e^*_i\Bigr)(e)\Bigr|>\sqrt{\theta}\Bigl|\Bigl(\sum_{i\in I}\|x^*_i\|e^*_i\Bigr)(e)\Bigr|.$$ Then with $x=(a_ix_i)_{i\in I}$, $\|x\|_{E(X_i)}\leqslant 1$ and \begin{align*} x^*(x) & =\sum_{i\in I}x^*_i(x_i)a_ie^*_i(e_i)\geqslant \sqrt{\theta}\sum_{i\in I}\|x^*_i\|a_ie^*_i(e_i) \\ & =\sqrt{\theta}\Bigl(\sum_{i\in I}\|x^*_i\|e^*_i\Bigr)\Bigl(\sum_{i\in I}a_ie_i\Bigr)\geqslant \theta \Bigl\|\sum_{i\in I}\|x^*_i\|e^*_i\Bigr\|_{E^*}.\end{align*}
